# python numpy double array, can't show image

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get multiple gray images in a double matrix, so I can later apply PCA on it, but I was wondering why the following doesn't work:

**input multidimensional numpy array (gray image)**

```
darray = np.empty([2,270,270], dtype=int)
darray[0] = cv2.imread("img.png", 0)
print(darray[0].shape)
print(type(darray[0]))
print(darray[0])

cv2.imshow("face", darray[0])
cv2.waitKey(3000)
```

**output (only black image)**

```
(270, 270)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[11 12 13 ..., 33 34 35]
 [13 12 11 ..., 34 36 37]
 [14 13 12 ..., 33 34 35]
 ..., 
 [82 81 81 ..., 94 93 93]
 [82 81 81 ..., 96 95 95]
 [83 82 82 ..., 92 92 92]]
**Only black as image**
```

**input normal array (gray image)**

```
nparray = cv2.imread("img.png", 0)
print(nparray.shape)
print(type(nparray))
print(nparray)

cv2.imshow("face", nparray)
cv2.waitKey(3000)
```

**output (normal image)**

```
(270, 270)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[11 12 13 ..., 33 34 35]
 [13 12 11 ..., 34 36 37]
 [14 13 12 ..., 33 34 35]
 ..., 
 [82 81 81 ..., 94 93 93]
 [82 81 81 ..., 96 95 95]
 [83 82 82 ..., 92 92 92]]
**normal gray image**
```

Why does the first piece of code only return a black image and the second piece of code the normal image I read?

### System specs

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Python 2.7.3
- OpenCV 2.4.9

Comment: using: np.savetxt('darray.txt', darray[0]) or np.savetxt('nparray.txt', nparray) both give the same output file, so I don't understand why cv2.imshow() doesn't work on both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found at that the error lays in the encoding dtype=int should be dtype=np.uint8.

```
import numpy as np
darray = np.empty([2,270,270], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `darray[0] = cv2.imread("img.png", 0)`, which could only fit 1 channel of the image. Actually it should be 3 channels containing R, G and B. You could simply see `nparray.shape` in the second piece of code.

Comment: This is only true for color images. , 0) means the image is loaded as a gray image. Sorry I forgot to mention it's about a gray image. imread of a gray image has no channel information, otherwise the second piece of code with 'nparray.shape' would have returned (270, 270, 1)